# How do I get all custom methods in a class?

Tags: ruby, methods

```
module Test
  class A
    def hi
      p 'hi'
    end

    def bye
      p 'bye'
    end

    puts methods.sort
    p '---------'
    puts methods.sort - Object.methods
  end
end
```

The second `puts` does not print anything, the first one does not print 'hi' and 'bye'. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because both lines are executed in scope of `A` class itself, while `hi` and `bye` are *instance methods* of that class. Try this:

```
module Test
  class A
    def hi
      p 'hi'
    end

    def bye
      p 'bye'
    end

    puts instance_methods(false)
  end
end

# >> hi
# >> bye
```

When you pass `false` to `instance_methods`, you instruct it to not include methods of super classes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you confused yourself between `method` and `instance_methods`:

```
module Test
  class A
    def hi
      p 'hi'
    end

    def bye
      p 'bye'
    end

    puts instance_methods.sort
    p '---------'
    puts instance_methods.sort - Object.instance_methods
  end
end
```

Output:

```
[:!, :!=, :!~, :<=>, :==, :===, :=~, :__id__, :__send__, :bye, :class, :clone, :define_singleton_method, :display, :dup, :enum_for, :eql?, :equal?, :extend, :freeze, :frozen?, :hash, :hi, :inspect, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :instance_of?, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variables, :is_a?, :kind_of?, :method, :methods, :nil?, :object_id, :private_methods, :protected_methods, :public_method, :public_methods, :public_send, :remove_instance_variable, :respond_to?, :send, :singleton_class, :singleton_methods, :taint, :tainted?, :tap, :to_enum, :to_s, :trust, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?]
"---------"
[:bye, :hi]
```